# Get selected/highlighted Text out of GridView

Tags: c#

When I highlight/mark a text with my mouse in a GridView, is it possible to get access to this selected Text? I want to save it in a string variable when I click for example on a button. It's not important if I get that text via a GridView access or something else, I need simply the marked text. I tried to trigger <kbd>ctrl+c</kbd> by clicking the button to safe it in clipboard, but I had problems with `System.Windows.Forms`. I didn't find any events like gridview.GetSelectedText for example.

I made a controller and first of all I want to get access to the selected text in the gridView:

```
namespace XPress.Module.Controllers
{
    public class TransactionAddStringToCategoryKeywordController : ObjectViewController<ObjectView, Transaction>
    {
        private const string addStringToCategoryKeywordId = "AddStringToCategoryKeyword";
        private readonly SimpleAction addStringToCategoryKeyword;

        public TransactionAddStringToCategoryKeywordController()
        {
            addStringToCategoryKeyword = new SimpleAction(this, addStringToCategoryKeywordId, DevExpress.Persistent.Base.PredefinedCategory.Edit);
            addStringToCategoryKeyword.ImageName = "Action_Export";

            //addStringToCategoryKeyword.TargetObjectsCriteria = "Not IsNullOrEmpty([NameFull])";
            addStringToCategoryKeyword.SelectionDependencyType = SelectionDependencyType.RequireMultipleObjects;
            addStringToCategoryKeyword.Execute += TransactionAddStringToCategoryKeyword_Execute;
        }

        protected override void OnActivated()
        {
            base.OnActivated();

            addStringToCategoryKeyword.Active["test"] = true;
        }
    }
}
```

And I have access to the GridView:

```
    private void WinAlternatingRowsController_ViewControlsCreated(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GridListEditor listEditor = ((ListView)View).Editor as GridListEditor;

        if (listEditor != null)
        {
            DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.GridView gridView = listEditor.GridView;
        }
    }
```

Comment: winforms? or something else?

Comment: It is DevExpress

Comment: @Sax, please [edit] your question and add the code of the DevExpress control you have.

Comment: okay did that :)